# File.Exists always returning False c#

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I've searched ALL the related and duplication and they are either unanswered or using a different method, or a different language. The file and path DOES exists, and whats more, i feel that this is right under my nose. The code is here.

```
static void Main()
{
    string fileName = @"‪C:\Temp\eXample.txt";

    //FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);

    var isFileExisting = File.Exists(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine(isFileExisting);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Whats more, is that when I uncomment the FileInfo object, I receive an error stating "*The given path's format is not supported*". All i really wanna do is check if the file exists.

Comment: You've got a hidden character in the string. Delete the entire line and write it again, it will work. See here: http://i.imgur.com/2fn889P.png

Comment: have you tried not using the @"" syntax and escaping the \  characters like `"C:\\Temp\\eXample.txt" ?

Comment: maybe your path is not "Temp" but "Temp " with space?

Comment: @mckeejm, yes. That was my original syntax for the string.

Comment: Paste this path in the explorer and see if it opens the file. If not, then path is wrong. If yes, then delete this line and type it again, or use \\ to escape instead of `@`.

Comment: @Rob is correct. there is a Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING'  at the beginning of the string. You can see it if you inspect the HTML on the page.  I'm assuming it was copied in with your code.

Comment: @Rob, I've tried re-typing, and is still returns false (perhaps I do not understand what you mean (i feel that it is too easy of an attempt to just retype it again). what do you mean by hidden character?)

Comment: @"&#8234;C:\Temp\eXample.txt" is what the path actually is  that is the HTML code for the UA202 - UNICODE LEFT-TO-RIGHT

Comment: @R.H.Thorne Your string is *actually* @"ZC:\Temp\eXample.txt"` where `Z` is a character that does not render - and is an invalid character for a path. It's not visible, but it's there. You will need to delete the entire line and type it again - **do not copy + paste**. You can prove it is there by highlighting from the `C` and dragging right. The selection will jump to the start of the line.

Comment: Check Saeed's answer. I tried the original source code and indeed there's a character between the double quote and the D.

Comment: @Rob, Worked!! Thanks

Comment: @R.H.Thorne No worries:)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your string "C:\Temp\eXample.txt" is not what it looks like.

You get the *"The given path's format is not supported"* if the second character of your string is not a colon (:).

That'd lead me to think that **there's some sort of a UTF8 hidden character before your colon (:)**.  Just erase the whole thing and re-type your string.

Comment: Assumption confirmed. I took the original question code and there's a character before the "D" indeed.

Comment: @Rob, I cannot upvote comments yet, but I took your suggestion and confirmed it with Saeed Jahed. Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may have another problem as well, based on the results when you uncomment that line, but this excerpt from the [File.Exists() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) bears repeating:

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

Mostly, though, you should avoid calling `File.Exists()` in the first place. The File system is **volatile**, and therefore this function usually creates a *race condition* between when you make a check and when you try to access the file in code. Granted, as race conditions go it's usually pretty tame, but it is still there, meaning you still need a try/catch block there to handle the exception if access to the file fails. And since you need this anyway, why even bother to make the check? You'll save yourself a disk access by skipping it, and there's usually a way to avoid the need at all, such as using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.

Comment: That was my first though too, but you'll notice the incorrect format error that is mentioned.  That would pre-empt this behavior.